# Displaying a ToolBar above the Tabbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `scroll View`. Now i need to add a `tool bar` when a `button` is clicked (above the tab bar). Since this is a `scroll View`, even if the user scrolls the page down the tool bar should be visible right above the `toolbar`.

my solution so far;

1.) i added the `toolbar` to a `Window`, and display the window (But i don't want to use a Window). Is there a way to do this using a `UIView` ?

> My pseudocode : ToolBar ---(added to)--> UIWindow ----(display)--->
>   display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a containing view to house both your scroll view and the toolbar.  Initially have your scroll view the full size within the containing view. Resize it smaller on button press and add the toolbar below it.  When you hide the toolbar do the reverse (remove the toolbar from the containing view and resize the scroll view back to taking up the full view).